# questions on a segment of java server program

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the following segment of Java code, which was implemented as a simple server

```
public class testserver extends AbstractHandler
{
   public void handle(String target,
                   Request baseRequest,
                   HttpServletRequest request,
                   HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException
 {
    response.setContentType("movie/html");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>this is a test</h1>");
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Server server = new Server(1234);
    server.setHandler(new testserver());

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

}

I am kind of confusing about the logic of this code. In specific, in the "main" function, it has

```
server.setHandler(new testserver());
```

I know it is to create a new server. But this main function is included in the class of testserver itself. So it functions as calling itself recursively, and it will create a lot of testserver. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method is not called when a new instance of the class is created. It's called by the system to start the entire process going.

Answer (score 0):

No. The `main` method serves as the entry point for a java program. It is called once, and in this case an instance of testserver is created. Actually creating the instance does not invoke the main method again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `import` statements to make proper head or tails of this, so we know exactly which class `Server` is. I expect that this is a test harness for some web server framework (perhaps Jetty embedded).

EDIT: yeah, its Jetty. `main` is only run once, when the JVM is started with this class as its target. It will create a single `Server` instance and then create a single `testserver` instance (not multiple instances). The `testserver` instance will then process the requests.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` method is the entry point into your class called by the JVM.  The call to

```
new testserver()
```

is creating a new instance of the class via the default no-args constructor.  The main method is static (or class-level), so you do not actually have an instance of testserver until you invoke the constructor.